# Angular 2 : Is it possible to bind to 'template'?

Tags: angular

> Is it possible to have some mark-up in a variable so I can pass it
>   into child components? For example I have three controls which are
>   different only by error message. I would like to have only one control
>   and pass error html or entire error component as a parameter. I could
>   do such with text but not with html. Here is the sketch of idea:

```
  @Component({
      selector: 'app',
      template: `
        <template #rr>
          <div>text</div>
        </template>

        {{rr}}
      `
     })
     export class App {
     }
```

Expected output:

```
 <div>text</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I correctly understand your question (provide some content to another component), I think that you could leverage `ng-content`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'template',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class TemplateComponent {
  (...)
}
```

and use the component like that in the `App` one:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <template #rr>
      <div>text</div>
    </template>
  `,
  directives: [ TemplateComponent ]
})
export class App {
}
```

If you want to reference something in the ng-content within the `TemplateComponent`, you can leverage `@ContentChild` decorator (see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ContentChild-var.html).

Comment: hi!. I got a question related to your answer if you could help. After implementing your answer what will be the DOM output? is it like 1) `<template><div><div>text</div></div></template>` or 2) `<div><div>text</div></div>`?

Comment: Okay thanks. so it doesn't like `transclude` from `angular1` but it does the same thing though except removing root tag...